# What does it mean to drop support for Internet Explorer 6?

Tags: websites, legacy, internet-explorer

[image: youtube ie6]

When Facebook, Youtube, and even Microsoft themselves say that they've "dropped support for IE6", what do they really mean? Youtube still functionally works fine in IE6. If they mean that they've dropped support for visual appearance and fancy features, then their point is moot. Web developers have degraded IE6's appearance and fancy feature set since the dawn of time.

So what does all this IE6 bashing from top companies mean for us web developers today? There's no big website that has dropped dropped *functionality* support for IE6 because they're scared that they would lose the 5% or so customers that are still using it. Until the day Google itself blocks IE6 from searching, thereby lowering IE6's market share to near 0%, I don't see how this "support dropping" accomplishes anything.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a practical solvable problem here: can you revise your question to ask a specific question that requires the unique insights from other programmers and isn't a rant about other companies' practices?

Answer (score 10):

It means that they no longer test the site in IE6 and, when it inevitably breaks, they will not make fixing it a priority.

Comment: They say they never test it in IE6, but they still do. It works perfectly fine up to this day in IE6.

Comment: Just because it works, does not mean they tested it.  If something breaks later, they are not obligated to fix it...  That said, they may decide to fix it anyway.

Comment: @JoJo: Just because it works, doesn't mean they've tested it. They have been supporting IE6 for a long time and their code is probably pretty robust. That said, if someone reports a major bug in IE6 which is a really simple fix, I'm sure they'll fix it. All they're saying is that they don't guarantee that they will, at least not quickly; if you want to be SURE that you can use YouTube all the time, upgrade.

Comment: @JoJo: This just means, that by now it didn't break. It doesn't have to. It just means they don't care if this should ever happen. There are far more browsers out there than the five that Youtube lists and most of them work well enough, if Youtube (or whoever) supports them or not.

Comment: @JoJo: I work at one of those "large" companies, and believe me, we definitly *don't* test in IE6 anymore. Starting this month, we won't be testing in IE7 anymore either.